# How to serialise Enums as both Object Shape and default string?

Tags: java, json, serialization, enums, jackson

For an enum with attributes, eg:

```java
public enum Thing {
  THING_A("a"),
  THING_B("b");

  private String thing;

  private Thing(String thing) {
    this.thing = thing;
  }

  // Getters...
}
```

`Jackson` serializes as the name of the values, eg:

```java
mapper.writeValueAsString(Thing.THING_A)); // "THING_A"
```

If we add the annotation to treat serialisation as an object:
`@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)`
it will serialize the attributes:

```java
mapper.writeValueAsString(Thing.THING_A)); // "{"thing":"a"}"
```

I'd like to be able to decide, *during serialization*, which of these methods to use.  Because this spans a large number of enums, I'd rather not edit each one.  Is there a good way to do this?

eg: something like this would be great:

```java
mapper.writeValueAsString(Thing.THING_A, JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT); // "{"thing":"a"}"
mapper.writeValueAsString(Thing.THING_A, JsonFormat.Enum.DEFAULT); // "THING_A"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat` is an annotation you can implement your own `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector` and return value you want for all your enums. Simple example you can find below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(AnnotationIntrospector.pair(new DynamicEnumAnnotationIntrospector(), new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector()));

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(Thing.THING_A));
    }
}

class DynamicEnumAnnotationIntrospector extends AnnotationIntrospector {

    @Override
    public Version version() {
        return new Version(1, 0, 0, "Dynamic enum object", "your.package", "jackson.dynamic.enum");
    }

    @Override
    public JsonFormat.Value findFormat(Annotated memberOrClass) {
        final Class<?> rawType = memberOrClass.getRawType();
        if (rawType.isEnum() && rawType.getPackage().getName().startsWith("your.package")) {
            return JsonFormat.Value.forShape(JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT);
        }

        return super.findFormat(memberOrClass);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"thing":"a"}
```

Now, you can create two instances of `ObjectMapper` and for one configure your own annotation introspector and second one leave with default. If you really want to use it in dynamic way you can create one `ObjectMapper` for each available `Shape` value and select required one for a given shape:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat.Shape;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.AnnotationIntrospector;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

        for (Shape shape : Shape.values()) {
            ObjectMapper mapper = factory.getWithEnumShapeSetTo(shape);
            System.out.println(shape + " => " + mapper.writeValueAsString(Thing.THING_A));
        }
    }
}

class JsonFactory {
    private final AnnotationIntrospector defaultIntrospector = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
    private final EnumMap<Shape, ObjectMapper> instances = new EnumMap<>(Shape.class);

    public JsonFactory() {
        final List<Shape> notAllowed = Arrays.asList(Shape.BOOLEAN, Shape.BINARY);
        Arrays.stream(Shape.values())
                .filter(shape -> !notAllowed.contains(shape))
                .forEach(shape -> instances.put(shape, createNewWithEnumShape(shape)));
    }

    private ObjectMapper createNewWithEnumShape(Shape shape) {
        DynamicEnumAnnotationIntrospector enumIntrospector = new DynamicEnumAnnotationIntrospector(shape);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(AnnotationIntrospector.pair(enumIntrospector, defaultIntrospector));

        return mapper;
    }

    public ObjectMapper getWithEnumShapeSetTo(Shape shape) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(shape);

        final ObjectMapper mapper = instances.get(shape);
        if (mapper == null) {
            return new ObjectMapper();
        }

        return mapper;
    }
}

class DynamicEnumAnnotationIntrospector extends AnnotationIntrospector {

    private final Shape shape;

    public DynamicEnumAnnotationIntrospector(Shape shape) {
        this.shape = Objects.requireNonNull(shape);
    }

    @Override
    public Version version() {
        return new Version(1, 0, 0, "Dynamic enum shape", "your.package", "jackson.dynamic.enum");
    }

    @Override
    public JsonFormat.Value findFormat(Annotated memberOrClass) {
        final Class<?> rawType = memberOrClass.getRawType();
        if (rawType.isEnum() && rawType.getPackage().getName().startsWith("your.package")) {
            return JsonFormat.Value.forShape(shape);
        }

        return super.findFormat(memberOrClass);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
ANY => "THING_A"
NATURAL => "THING_A"
SCALAR => "THING_A"
ARRAY => 0
OBJECT => {"thing":"a"}
NUMBER => 0
NUMBER_FLOAT => 0
NUMBER_INT => 0
STRING => "THING_A"
BOOLEAN => "THING_A"
BINARY => "THING_A"
```

Above code of course is overkill but I wanted to show possibilities we have. We have only 3 different outputs so you can group values with the same output and create maximum 3 different `ObjectMappers`.

Answer (score 1):

The above question is similar and has already been answered.
[Jackson ObjectMapper set JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY without annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44246074/jackson-objectmapper-set-jsonformat-shape-array-without-annotation).

You can use custom object mapper specific for the Enum and different object mapper for other classes.